# How to expand a partition inside a VMware Linux VM

Tags: partitioning, vmware-player

I need to expand a partition inside a Debian VM on a Windows host (and in the process move a small partition).

I think I should use a Live CD (Which one?)

Can I mount an ISO to the VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- shutdown the vm
- go to the HDD options and scale it up
- resize the partition from within linux

how to exactly resize depends on the filesystem,
the quick and easy solution would be a live cd like the [gparted live cd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) ,
you can just mount the ISO in the VM and boot from it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean Live CD? Just out of curiosity... I can't give you exact instructions because I haven't done it for Linux in a long time, but I have done it recently for a Windows VM so I think the process should be almost the same. You need to create a new disk for your Debian VM and add it to the disk inventory in VMware. Then fire up your Debian OS [and check out this link](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch27_:_Expanding_Disk_Capacity). I that should be able to do what you need. Hopefully this helps

Comment: This is different.  I want to expand the current main partition of my VM.

Comment: Sorry. What is your VM software? VMware Workstation? VMWare server? VirtualBox? VMWare workstation has an expand utility built into the GUI that will allow you to modify the size of the existing virtual disk. GoTo your VM, Edit Machine Settings, Hard Disk, Utilities, and finally Expand... Expand your disk,  then you just need to figure out how to grow the OS file system to take advantage of the additional space